# The use of が, は and を in 私は総てを愛している

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, particle-を, は-and-が

Is the を interchangeable with が in this case?

And if I say 私が総てを愛している does it mean  'I'm everything that I love'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-outside-of-embedded-clauses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

愛する is a straightforward transitive verb. Therefore, が always marks a subject (i.e. who loves), and を always marks an object (i.e. who/what is loved). は, as a topic marker, usually marks a subject but sometimes marks an object (See: [Why can は and を sometimes be used interchangeably?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23378/5010)). As far as 愛する/愛している is used in a simple sentence like this, が and を are not interchangeable.

> 私は総てを愛している

This is a simple sentence that means "I love everything." Since すべて ("everything") is an object, 私 is clearly the subject (and topic).

> 私が総てを愛している

This means "*I* love everything" (with emphasized "I"). 私 is the subject, and すべて is the object, anyway. Usually a sentence that describes a fact like this uses は, but when you use が instead of は, it has an [exhaustive-listing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010) function.

---

"I'm everything that I love" translates to 私は私が愛するすべてである (what a narcissistic statement!). You need to be familiar with relative clauses to understand this sentence.

---

There are a few exceptional words and constructions which can take both が and を. Please see the following questions for details. (Note that these are not related to your usage of 愛する.)

- With potential expressions: [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)
- With tai-form: [が vs を in sentences of desire (-たい)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15171/5010)
- With certain adjectives and verbs: [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010)