# What would happen if I use は or が in 今日何を食べたいですか?

Tags: particles, syntax

> 今日何を食べたいですか 
> What do you want to eat today?

In other words, what would happen if I say:

> 今日何は食べたいですか ?
>
> 今日何が食べたいですか ?

(I want to know the rough meaning of the sentence even if the sentence is wrong.)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14986/9831 -- `が can also mark objects of...  ～たい form and the ~える・れる potential form...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can say...

> 今日は何**を**食べたいですか？
>   今日は何**が**食べたいですか？

を is the object marker. You can use が here instead, since が can mark the object of the ～たい form verb.

Your second sentence:

> 今日何**は**食べたいですか？

would be incorrect. You don't use the topic/contrastive は for a  question word.
◎「何が～～？」 ◎「誰が～～？」 ◎「いつ(が)～～？」etc.
×「何は～～？」 ×「誰は～～？」 ×「いつは～～？」 etc.

As you know, は is basically the topical/thematic particle (主題の「は」) or the contrastive particle (対比の「は」), and can replace が, を. But it can't be attached to the question word 何、どこ、誰、いつ etc... (cos 何、どこ etc. can't be a topic/theme of a sentence, nor can they be contrasted with some other element of the sentence.)

Comment: So both 今日は何を食べたいですか？ and
今日は何が食べたいですか？ would sound okay for a native speaker?

Comment: そうですね、both sound okay to me.  I think 「何**が**食べたいですか」 is a bit more common, though.

Answer (score 1):

While both 「は」 and 「が」 as particles are "subject indicators" (please take note that I am not sure of the actual linguistic term for this), they emphasise different things.

「は」places emphasis on what comes **after** it, ergo:

> 今【いま】はいいかんじです。
>
> (I feel) *good* now.
>
> 今日【きょう】は疲【つか】れます。
>
> (I) am *tired* today.

In your hypothetical example, you'd be placing emphasis on 「食べたい」, as in "What do you want to *eat*?" It feels like asking if you *want to eat "what"*.

As ericfromabeno states (along with Chocolate's very helpful answer), using 「は」for this kind of statement is unnatural. I think 「を」is still more appropriate particle to use in this sentence.

「が」places emphasis on what comes **before** it, ergo:

> チョコレートが好【す】きです。
>
> "I like *chocolate*."
>
> 気分【きぶん】が悪【わる】いです。
>
> "I *feel* bad."

Your hypothetical example places the emphasis on 「何」, as in "*What* do you want to eat?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome answer. So using 「は」or「が」is not wrong. It just puts emphasis in different elements? (Maybe some of them would sound strange to a native speaker?)

Comment: I have heard and seen 今日何が食べたいですか ?  before, but the は version just sounds wrong to me.  Using は there makes it sound like you're asking "Do you want to eat some 'what', today?" ^_^

Comment: I hoped that by using the term "hypothetical", I would emphasise that they are not very common usage -- but I'm intrigued to see that 「が」is sometimes used in this particular statement. Seeing this statement with 「は」feels so unnatural, personally...